# Git wants to stage and commit internal LFS files

Tags: git, git-lfs

Me and my team have been using git LFS for a month now and everything has been working flawlessly. Today I made some small changes that I wanted to commit and push. The problem is that git suddenly wants to stage and commit the internal LFS files, more accurate the 'lfs' directory and the 'hooks' directory. Of course if I were to try this, than git would reject the push, because the binary files are larger than 150MB.

Git (2.26.1.windows.1) and git LFS (2.10.0) are both still installed. I am working on a Windows pc.

I tried using the command 'git lfs install' again but it only says 'Updated git hooks. Git LFS initialized.' but the problem is still there.

I was not able to find any post on the internet with a similar problem. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This typically should not happen.  If you're using WSL, then [there's a known issue on the Git LFS issue tracker](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4800), where in some cases the files are created in the incorrect location.  Unfortunately, nobody knows what the problem is and nobody has provided reproduction steps, so it can't be fixed until someone can provide that information.  Maybe it can be you.

However, if you're just on regular Windows, then this is [an already fixed issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4050) and you just need to upgrade to the latest version.  Normally, you can do that by just upgrading your Git version, since Git for Windows includes Git LFS.

I should also note that if you're on Windows, versions older than 3.1.3 have a security problem, and you should upgrade anyway.  That issue does not affect Unix systems.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I updated git and git LFS to the newest versions, but the problem still remained. I have WSL installed but I was not using it for this project.

I fixed my problem by copying my changes to a different folder, than doing 'git reset --hard' to an earlier commit that did not have this problem and finally I copied my changes over to the repository by hand. After doing this, the problem no longer occurred.

Comment: Right.  Upgrading doesn't fix the fact that you have untracked files, so cleaning them out is going to be necessary either way.